# How to select a link of a Record in the table contains multiple Rows of different class with same class name for each column

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```html
<table class="table hover" id="resultTable">            
<thead>
<tr>
<th rowspan="1" class="checkbox-col"><input type="checkbox" id="ohrmList_chkSelectAll" name="chkSelectAll" value=""></th>
<th rowspan="1" style="width:400" class="header"><a href="http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/core/viewDefinedPredefinedReports?sortField=name&amp;sortOrder=ASC" class="null">Report Name</a></th>
<th rowspan="1" style="width:95"><span class="headerCell"></span></th>
<th rowspan="1" style="width:95"><span class="headerCell"></span></th>
</tr>            
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td><input type="checkbox" id="ohrmList_chkSelectRecord_5" name="chkSelectRow[]" value="5"></td>                                <td class="left">PIM Sample Report</td>
<td class="left"><a href="/index.php/core/displayPredefinedReport?reportId=5">Run</a></td>
<td class="left"><a href="/index.php/core/definePredefinedReport?reportId=5">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td><input type="checkbox" id="ohrmList_chkSelectRecord_6" name="chkSelectRow[]" value="6"></td>                                <td class="left">Sample Report</td>
<td class="left"><a href="/index.php/core/displayPredefinedReport?reportId=6">Run</a></td>
<td class="left"><a href="/index.php/core/definePredefinedReport?reportId=6">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

I'm  a beginner to selenium, so I need a help to click a link (Run)of a Record from multiple Records in the table contains multiple Rows of different class with same class name for each column. I have attached the code snippet.

I tried this Xpath but is not working:

```
//table[@class='table hover']/tbody/tr/td[text()='PIM Sample Report'] and ./td[text()='Run']
```

can someone help me to figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below XPath :

```
//td[.="PIM Sample Report"]/following-sibling::td[.="Run"]/a
```

This should fetch the link `"Run"` preceded by `td` with text `"PIM Sample Report"`

Comment: It Worked:) Thank You Andersson

Comment: Welcome! You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem